# Theano in Centos 7 with error bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, c++, theano, theano-cuda

I got the error:

```
Problem occurred during compilation with the command line below:
/usr/bin/g++ -shared -g -O3 -fno-math-errno -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-write-strings -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -m64 -fPIC -I/scratch/user/tools/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/scratch/user/tools/anaconda2/include/python2.7 -I/scratch/user/tools/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof -L/scratch/user/tools/anaconda2/lib -fvisibility=hidden -o /home/user/.theano/compiledir_Linux-3.10-el7.x86_64-x86_64-with-centos-7.3.1611-Core-x86_64-2.7.13-64/tmpAKnaE0/d16654b784f584f17fdc481825fd2cca.so /home/user/.theano/compiledir_Linux-3.10-el7.x86_64-x86_64-with-centos-7.3.1611-Core-x86_64-2.7.13-64/tmpAKnaE0/mod.cpp -lpython2.7

['nvcc', '-shared', '-O3', '-m64', '-Xcompiler', '-DCUDA_NDARRAY_CUH=c72d035fdf91890f3b36710688069b2e,-DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION,-fPIC,-fvisibility=hidden', '-Xlinker', '-rpath,/home/user/.theano/compiledir_Linux-3.10-el7.x86_64-x86_64-with-centos-7.3.1611-Core-x86_64-2.7.13-64/cuda_ndarray', '-I/scratch/user/tools/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/sandbox/cuda', '-I/scratch/user/tools/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include', '-I/scratch/user/tools/anaconda2/include/python2.7', '-I/scratch/user/tools/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof', '-L/scratch/user/tools/anaconda2/lib', '-o', '/home/user/.theano/compiledir_Linux-3.10-el7.x86_64-x86_64-with-centos-7.3.1611-Core-x86_64-2.7.13-64/cuda_ndarray/cuda_ndarray.so', 'mod.cu', '-lcublas', '-lpython2.7', '-lcudart']

In file included from /home/user/.theano/compiledir_Linux-3.10-el7.x86_64-x86_64-with-centos-7.3.1611-Core-x86_64-2.7.13-64/tmpAKnaE0/mod.cpp:2:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/iostream:38:28: fatal error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory
 #include 
                            ^
compilation terminated.
```

after installing theano Theano (0.9.0) on Centos 7 with Cuda 8.0. It looks like bits/c++config.h can not be found. However, it has been compiled in /usr/include/c++/4.8.5/i686-redhat-linux/bits/

```
atomic_word.h  c++allocator.h  c++io.h      cpu_defines.h  ctype_inline.h   error_constants.h  gthr-default.h  gthr-posix.h   messages_members.h  os_defines.h  stdtr1c++.h
basic_file.h   c++config.h     c++locale.h  ctype_base.h   cxxabi_tweaks.h  extc++.h           gthr.h          gthr-single.h  opt_random.h        stdc++.h      time_members.h
```

Thanks

Comment: A guess - try `export  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/i686-redhat-linux` before the compilation.

Comment: @cdarke Thanks, do you mean before installing theano using pip install theano?

Comment: I used export CPATH=$CPATH:/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/i686-redhat-linux and the error is disappeared.